# Find neighbour cells and react accordingly

Tags: python, simulation

I am making a simulation for a project and need to get cells to multiply when a male and female meet. I am unsure where to put the code and unsure where I need to put it into an array at first. I have been stuck on it. Also having trouble with changing of color of the cell according to their development stage.

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
from shrimp import Shrimp

XMAX = 1500
YMAX = 1500   

def main():
    monkeys = []

    for i in range(70):
        randX = random.randint(0,XMAX)
        randY = random.randint(0,YMAX)
        monkeys.append(Shrimp([randX,randY]))       
       # print(monkeys[i])

    for i in range(50):
        print("\n ### TIMESTEP ",i, "###")
        xvalues = []
        yvalues = []
        sizes = []

        for m in monkeys:
            m.stepChange()
            #print(m)
            xvalues.append(m.pos[0])
            yvalues.append(m.pos[1])
            sizes.append(m.getSize())
            print(m)



        plt.scatter(xvalues, yvalues, s=sizes)   # Note plt origin is bottom left 
        plt.xlim(0,XMAX)
        plt.ylim(0,YMAX)
        plt.show()
        time.sleep(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
import random
YELLOW = (225,225,0)
RED = (0,0,225)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
""""
class Shrimp():
    time2hatch = 4
    states = ["egg","subadults", "adult","dead"]
    deathrate = {"egg": 0.01, "subadult":0.02, "adult":0.02}


    def __init__(self, pos,):
        self.pos = pos
        self.state = self.states[0]
        self.age = 0
        self.time2hatch = random.randint(4,20)




    def __str__(self):
        return self.state + " @ " + str(self.pos)

    def stepChange(self):
        self.age += 1
        if self.state == "egg":
            self.pos[1] -= 5
            if self.age > self.time2hatch:
                self.state = "subadults"

        else:
            xmov = random.randint (-3,3)
            ymov = random.randint (-3,3)
            self.pos[0] += xmov
            self.pos[1] += ymov


        if self.state == "subadults":
            if self.age > self.time2hatch + 15:
                adultsex = ["male", "female"]
                self.state = random.choice(adultsex)
            #print(self.state)
        else:
            xmov = random.randint (-10,10)
            ymov = random.randint (-10,10)
            self.pos[0] += xmov
            self.pos[1] += ymov



    def getColour(m):
        if m.state == "egg":
            colour = YELLOW
        elif m.state =="subadult":
            colour = RED
        else:colour = BLACK

        return colour

    def getSize(m):
        if m.state == "egg":
            size = 5
        elif m.state == "subadults" :
            size = 10
        elif m.state == "adult":
            size = 30
        else: 
            size = 100

        return size
```

Comment: here is the Class code

Comment: I guess the first question is what do you actually mean by adjacent. It looks like you have already decide on some sort of discrete integer coordinate system, but real shrimp don't live in discrete integer locations :-)?

Comment: There I have edited it and added my 'class code' as well any help would be amazing. I have been stuck for over 20 hrs now....